# Table aliases in SQL query

Tags: sql

I've got this query where I'm trying to use column identifiers (I don't know how it's called), but some appear to be working, and other not.

```
SELECT R1.EC_Date, R1.JO_Num, R1.EC_Intitule, R1.EC_Sens, R1.EC_RefPiece, R1.EC_Piece, R1.CG_Num, R1.EC_Reference, R1.JM_Date, R1.EC_Jour, R2.EC_Lettrage, R2.EC_Pointage
FROM ((F_COMPTEA CA INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREA EA ON CA.CA_Num = EA.CA_Num)
               INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREC EC ON EA.EC_No = EC.EC_No) R1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT * 
            FROM F_ECRITUREC
            WHERE (CG_Num LIKE '401%' OR CG_Num LIKE '411%')
            AND (JO_Num = 'RAN' OR JO_Num = 'ACH' OR JO_Num = 'VTE')
            AND EC_RefPiece IN (
                SELECT EC_RefPiece
                FROM F_ECRITUREA EA INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREC EC ON EA.EC_No = EC.EC_No
                WHERE EC_Jour BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
                AND JM_Date = '2013-01-07'
                AND JO_Num = 'ACH'
                AND EA.CA_Num LIKE '%')) R2
        ON R1.EC_RefPiece = R2.EC_RefPiece
WHERE EC_Jour BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
AND JM_Date = '2013-01-07'
AND JO_Num = 'ACH'
AND EA.CA_Num LIKE '%';
```

In that case, the CA, EA and EC identifiers are working correctly, and the JOIN is working, but when I try to add the last JOIN with the R1 AND R2 identifiers, it doesn't appears to be working, and I can't find the difference.
The errors I have are : Incorrect syntax near R1/R2.
I've tried to use AS, but it's not working either, so I'm sure if it's a syntax issue, or just the result of a problem elsewhere.
It's MS SQL by the way.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: They are called *table aliases*. Please mention clearly what errors you get.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near R1
Incorrect syntax near R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT` clause is missing for subquery `R1`.
And you probably no longer need `WHERE` conditions in your outer select. You applied them in `R2`. But for sure, you're no longer can reference `EA` columns in outer select. Only R1 and R2 aliases available in your outer query.

That being said I believe your query should look something like this

```
SELECT R1.EC_Date, 
       R1.JO_Num, 
       R1.EC_Intitule, 
       R1.EC_Sens, 
       R1.EC_RefPiece, 
       R1.EC_Piece, 
       R1.CG_Num, 
       R1.EC_Reference, 
       R1.JM_Date, 
       R1.EC_Jour, 
       R2.EC_Lettrage, 
       R2.EC_Pointage
  FROM 
(
    SELECT * -- you has been missing SELECT here
      FROM F_COMPTEA CA JOIN F_ECRITUREA EA 
        ON CA.CA_Num = EA.CA_Num JOIN F_ECRITUREC EC 
        ON EA.EC_No = EC.EC_No
) R1 JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
      FROM F_ECRITUREC
     WHERE (CG_Num LIKE '401%' OR CG_Num LIKE '411%')
       AND (JO_Num = 'RAN' OR JO_Num = 'ACH' OR JO_Num = 'VTE')
       AND EC_RefPiece IN 
       (
            SELECT EC_RefPiece
              FROM F_ECRITUREA EA INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREC EC ON EA.EC_No = EC.EC_No
             WHERE EC_Jour BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
               AND JM_Date = '2013-01-07'
               AND JO_Num = 'ACH'
               AND EA.CA_Num LIKE '%'
        )
) R2 ON R1.EC_RefPiece = R2.EC_RefPiece
-- WHERE EC_Jour BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
--   AND JM_Date = '2013-01-07'
--   AND JO_Num = 'ACH'
--   AND EA.CA_Num LIKE '%' you're no longer can reference `EA` columns in outer select. Only R1 and R2 aliases available in your outer query
```

Comment: I just had to replace the SELECT * with the column names I needed, otherwise there was an error about a column being there twice. Working like a charm though, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
R1.EC_Date,
R1.JO_Num,
R1.EC_Intitule,
R1.EC_Sens,
R1.EC_RefPiece,
R1.EC_Piece,
R1.CG_Num,
R1.EC_Reference,
R1.JM_Date,
R1.EC_Jour,

R2.EC_Lettrage,
R2.EC_Pointage

FROM

(SELECT *
FROM
F_COMPTEA 
INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREA EA
ON CA.CA_Num = EA.CA_Num
INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREC EC
ON EA.EC_No = EC.EC_No
) AS R1


INNER JOIN
(
SELECT * 
FROM
F_ECRITUREC
WHERE
(CG_Num LIKE '401%' OR CG_Num LIKE '411%')
AND (JO_Num = 'RAN' OR JO_Num = 'ACH' OR JO_Num = 'VTE')
AND EC_RefPiece IN (SELECT EC_RefPiece FROM F_ECRITUREA EA INNER JOIN F_ECRITUREC EC ON EA.EC_No = EC.EC_No
WHERE EC_Jour BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
AND JM_Date = '2013-01-07'
AND JO_Num = 'ACH'
AND EA.CA_Num LIKE '%')

) AS R2

ON R1.EC_RefPiece = R2.EC_RefPiece

WHERE 
R2.EC_Jour BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
AND R2.JM_Date = '2013-01-07'
AND R2.JO_Num = 'ACH'
--THERE IS NO CONDITION WITHIN THIS LIKE?
AND R2.CA_Num LIKE '%'
```